# Lazy load data for ViewPager Items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `Fragment` that contains a `ViewPager` , now the `ViewPager` contains 3 different items , i.e each item(Page) contains a `ListView` and each list hase it Own `Adapter` , I cant use `FragmentPagerAdapter`

sine the `ViewPager` lives in a `Fragment` .

Should i Load all the Three `ListViews` Data in the `Fragment` and pass it to the `PagerAdapter` ?

Comment: did you find answer for this?

Comment: yes do you want the answer ?

Comment: can you please share a hint? that will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
   public  abstract class BaseLazyFragment extends Fragment {

    protected boolean isVisible;


    /**
     * to judge if is visible to user 
     * @param isVisibleToUser
     */
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if(getUserVisibleHint()) {
            this.isVisible = true;
            onVisible();
        } else {
            this.isVisible = false;
            onInvisible();
        }

    }


    /**
     * when the  fragment is not visible to user 
     */
    protected void onInvisible() {
        Loggy.e("do  onInvisible");
    }

    /**
     * when the fragment is visible to user 
     * 
     * lazyload
     */
    protected void onVisible() {
        Loggy.e("do  onVisible---");
        lazyLoad();
    }

    protected abstract void lazyLoad();

    }
```

*then you can create a customer fragment extends BaseLazyFragment
for example*

```
   public class NewsFragment extends BaseLazyFragment {

    private boolean isPrepared; 
    //a flag to judge init action has finished

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_page,null);

        //do init

        // when init is finish , set flag true;
        isPrepared = true;

        lazyLoad();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void lazyLoad() {

         // according this judge, can prevent nullpointerexception 
        if(!isPrepared || !isVisible){
            return;
        }

        // assignment the view 
        // get data from network assignment to varible
    }
}
```

> setUserVisibleHint()

the first time when the fragment create setUserVisibleHint() method is header than onCreateView(),so the lazyLoad() method may throw NullPointerException because the oncreateView() is not invoke, so  you should to create a flag variable --> isPrepared.

> onCreateView()

[reference link](http://www.jcodecraeer.com/a/anzhuokaifa/androidkaifa/2014/1021/1813.html)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it depends how big is your data which are you loading?

If it is big, try to download ie. 10 items for each page and pass that data to adapters and cache it. After what, implement lazy loader (like in google play app), which downloads your next items for your correct page, not for all.

So all your three pages would have data to display on a first load, if user wants more, he can navigate to the bottom of your list, press "load more" and get more items :)

From my experience this solution works fine. Of course server side should be adopted for this kind of loader.

Also there are more considerations, ie. maybe your data is "very live". So you have to think about it.