# Viewpage+tablayout: Why fragment 2 3 start when fragment 1 called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image: Tablayout]

When I start application then Tab Home started but tab Cung Hoàng Đạo also starts .When I select tab Cung Hoàng Đạo  then tab 12 Con Giap and Tử Vi start.

I want them to start only when they are selected.
Sorry for my grammar.
Thanks everybody.

This is my code:

```
public class ViewPageContainerFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private  ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private boolean[] isTabsSelected = new boolean[5];
    private OnTabChangeListener mOnTabChangeListener;
    private int countSelectedTab = 1;
    @Override
    public void init() {
        tabLayout =  (TabLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager =  (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public void setEvent() {
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        isTabsSelected[0] = true;
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected: "+position);
                if (position != 0) {
                    if (!isTabsSelected[position]
                            && adapter.getItem(position).getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1
                            && getCurrentFragment(position) instanceof OnTabChangeListener) {
                        mOnTabChangeListener = (OnTabChangeListener) getCurrentFragment(position);
                        mOnTabChangeListener.onTabSelected();
                    }
                } else if (adapter.getItem(0).getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "position = 0");
                }
                if (!isTabsSelected[position]) {
                    isTabsSelected[position] = true;
                    countSelectedTab++;
                    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(countSelectedTab);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue() {

    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_viewpage;
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter.addFrag(new HomeContainerFragment(), "Home");
        adapter.addFrag(new CungHoangDaoContainerFragment(), "Cung Hoàng Đạo");
        adapter.addFrag(new ConGiapContainerFragment(), "12 Con Giáp");
        adapter.addFrag(new TuViContainerFragment(), "Tử Vi");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public Fragment getCurrentFragment(int position) {
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        return fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container_framelayout);
    }
    public interface OnTabChangeListener {
        void onTabSelected();
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code where you are calling these tab fragments

Comment: I  has update code on post, tks so much!

Comment: `setOffscreenPageLimit()` won't work to meet **only start when is slected** ,the `pageLimit` means **the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state**,that is ,`FragmentA+B+C` ,if set the limit==1,then Fragment B will be loaded with A at first launch.
This should be the very answer  [Viewpager Lazy load data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418568/viewpager-lazy-load-data)

Answer (score 1):

ViewPager by default preload several page in advanced for smoother navigation. You customize this behavior by extending ViewPager and overriding **setOffscreenPageLimit** method:

Documentation  Link [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

> **public void setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)**
>
> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this 
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>
> This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once, less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as the user pages back and forth.
>
> You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex layouts. This setting defaults to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The setOffscreenPageLimit() don't work. You must stop the preload of the ViewPager,it means that the ViewPager need to load data lazyly. Just like this.

```
public class FragmentSample extends Fragment{
    ...  
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
           // load your data
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)` method, add this -

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

From the docs,

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.